# GAE - How to customise AppEngine logging

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, log4j

I been try to looks this before but I cant find. So I suggest to ask here.

My goal is to customise teh logging like log4j do into its log4j.properties

I have entry on my logging.properties on GAE.

```
.level = ALL

log4j.logger.com.winzter.ams.utils=INFO
```

Since, my root logging set to ALL and **com.winzter.ams.utils** set to INFO, Im expecting that in my utils package and classes log only INFO but that's not what happen. GAE still logs all including debug/fine.

Comment: Have you added the logging property file into your appengine-xml as explained here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime?hl=en#Logging ?

Comment: Definitely yes, setting in **appengine-web.xml** already exists upon creating the appengine web.
`  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
`

And **logging.properties** file already exists in **WEB-INF**.

Comment: @da_re,

One more follow-up info, if I change level into INFO, I was only see logging the INFO log level. At that post I know the I modifying teh right file and level logger in working. The  Only thing is not working was package log level not working.